# How to send idToken to AppSync graphQL to authenticate query (OIDC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am using App sync to create a graphQl API with OIDC to authenticate the users, When I test the oidc token in the aws query console it works fine but from my frontend it says **Error: No current user**

> const todoData = await API.graphql(
> {
> query: createRoom,
> variables: { advertiser_name: 'test2' },
> authMode: 'OPENID_CONNECT',
> authToken: 'MyToken',
> }

Which one would be the proper way to send this token using amplify client to fetch Appsync?

Answer (score 2):

The Amplify JavaScript library sends the **AccessToken** instead of the **IdToken** on GraphQL requests. Unfortunately, the AWS console for AppSync sends does the opposite: it sends the **IdToken** instead of the **AccessToken**.

See GitHub issue for more information: [Access token passed to appsync resolver causes missing email claim #4751](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4751#issuecomment-613717344)

However, you can override the Authorization header for GraphQL to send the **IdToken**:

```js
Amplify.configure({
  API: {
    graphql_headers: async () => {
      const session = await Auth.currentSession();
      return {
        Authorization: session.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
      };
    },
  },
});
```

It should be noted that using the **IdToken** instead of the **AccessToken** might cause security issues.